# 2 How do I solve this equation involving a logarithm?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

2 How do I solve this equation involving a logarithm? 3

Comment: start by $\log(x/a)=\log(x)-\log(a)$ then change the basis of the logarithm and you should be good...

Answer (score 1):

$$\log_2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) = \log_3\left(\frac{2+x}{3}\right)$$

$$\log_2(x)-\log_2(2) = \log_3(2+x)-\log_3(3)$$

$$\log_2(x)-1 = \log_3(2+x)-1$$

$$\log_2(x) = \log_3(2+x)$$

$$\log_3(2+x)=\frac{\log_{10}(2+x)}{\log_{10}(3) }$$

$$\log_2(x) = \frac{\log_{10}(x)}{\log_{10}(2)}$$

$$\therefore \frac{\log_{10}(2+x)}{\log_{10}(3)} = \frac{\log_{10}(x)}{\log_{10}(2)}$$
From now on, we'll write $\log_{10}(a)$ as $\log(a)$.

$$\log(2+x)\log(2) = \log(3)\log(x)$$

$$\log(2+x) = \frac{\log(3)}{\log(2)}\log(x)$$

$$ \frac{\log(3)}{\log(2)} \approx 1.585\ldots$$

$$\log(2+x) = 1.585\log(x)$$

$$\log(2+x) = \log(x^{1.585})$$

I don't have the time to finish off the answer right now, I'll do it later. Hopefully it should be obvious, just subtract and multiply out.

Answer (score -1):

Use the properties of the log function:

$\log_a {\frac{b}{c}} = \log_a b -\log_a c$

and $\log_a x = \log_a b \times \log_b x$.